# How to stop using file after error in deserialization?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm using : `boito = Serializer.DeSerializeObject("XOPC.xml");` with try catch.

so here is method :

```
   public static ObjectToSerialize DeSerializeObject(string filename)
   {
      ObjectToSerialize objectToSerialize;
      Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
      BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      objectToSerialize = (ObjectToSerialize)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
      stream.Close();
      return objectToSerialize;
   }
```

I had changed structure and it's failing to DeSerialize this file but on next step when I'm trying to serialize it again I'm getting error : "This file is using by another process" and I can't access it.

So how to stop using file after error in deserialization ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing the stream if an exception is thrown. Use a `using` statement:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    return (ObjectToSerialize) bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

This is equivalent to disposing of the stream in a `finally` block.

This isn't just about deserialization - you should (almost<sup>1</sup>) *always* use `using` statements for unmanaged resources. Any explicit call to `Close` or `Dispose` (outside a `Dispose` implementation merely releasing composed resources) is suspicious.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Very* occasionally you want to leave a resource open on success, but close it if something else fails. This is rare and awkward.